# How would you use 裏切り in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I can't find much information on this word. I know that it means "backstabbing" or "betrayal", but there are little to no example sentences which use it. For example, would I use it in a sentence like "a backstabbing person", and if so, would this be along the lines of 裏切りな人 or something completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[裏切]{うら・ぎ}り` is just the noun form of the verb `[裏切]{うら・ぎ}る`.  So to describe a backstabbing person (backstabber), you can just say `[裏切]{うら・ぎ}る(者{もの}・人{ひと})`.  Although there is also the special compound noun `[裏切]{うら・ぎ}り者{もの}` for the same meaning.  There's a slight usage nuance that I can't quite put into words, but it's not so big that it's something to worry about.

And of course, the verb `[裏切]{うら・ぎ}る` conjugates as a [五段動詞]{ご・だん・どう・し}, the same as 切{き}る by itself.

There are many examples of this in the Bible, especially concerning Judas betraying Jesus.  You can search for the term `裏切` (leave off the okurigana) [online here](http://www.bible.or.jp/read/titletext.html) if you want to find some of these examples.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason I was thinking it was an adjective, probably because of how it is described as just "backstabbing" in most cases, which in English is generally used as an adjective. It makes so much more sense now.

Comment: 「裏切り者!」 - "You backstabber!"

Answer (score 0):

As the noun form, it can also be used simply like this.

彼の裏切りにカッとした。
(I, or someone else) flew into a rage at his **betrayal**.

Comment: Do you mean to say 「カッとした」?  「カットした」 means something completely different.

Comment: Ah, I actually never realized it was spelled like that.  Edited my post. Thanks for pointing that out!